# Symfony2 and MVC - Is extend controller a good practice?

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller, symfony-2.4

I have a simple and perhaps stupid question.

Using Symfony2 PHP framework i often work extending controllers like below (*of course it depends from the kind of work*):

```
    class MainController extends Controller{
        private $locale = array();

        protected function Locale() {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getManager();

                $this->locale = $em->getRepository('CommonLanguageBundle:Language')
            ->findBy(
                array('code' => $this->getRequest()
                    ->getLocale()
                )
            );
//      \Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($this->locale);
        return $this->locale[0];
    }
     //..
    }
    class StoreController extends MainController{
     function a_method() {
       $data = $this->Locale()->getId();
       //...
      }
    }
    class DefaultController extends StoreController {
     $data = $this->Locale()->getId();
     //...
    }
```

Is this a good practice?

Surfing on the web i found many articles but it isn't still so clear for me.

In the end, if it worked fine in Symfony2, would it be good in general for MVC pattern?

Comment: Your question is too broad, I suggest you to focus Symfony2, even if it's not sufficient to avoid the question to be closed.

Comment: I like doing that too, it's important for code-reuse. Also I've seen articles about extending bundles routes which require the use of it.

Comment: What is the *purpose* for which you're extending the class? This has nothing to do with MVC, but with OOP. If there's no benefit to extending a class, then you shouldn't do it. If there is, then do it.

Comment: @n.1 I don't think the question is too broad. A good answer might specify the fact that "Symfony2 allows this, while X framework does not but in general most of them allow it."

Comment: Consider updating your question and posting the source for your MainController.  That will give us some idea if it makes sense to extend from it or if the common functionality should be in some other class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I agree with you with "real benefits and utility", in fact i wrote "it depends from the kind of work". Of course, i didn't extend controller whereas it is unuseful. My question is related to those cases where there are _common methods, common repository's call and so on_.

Comment: As suggested from Cerad,l i updated the post with a common controller like example. It has no sense but it is just to give an idea

Comment: Per your example, I would use a request event listener to add the locale directly to the request object so all my controllers would have access to it without the need to extend.  I could post an example if you want.

Comment: it would be very appreciable whether you post an instance :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symfony [**is not**](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2) MVC framework. Symfony is [Service-oriented architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) framework. Generally cascading extending controllers doesn't make a sens.

Rather you should create [services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) and use it in whe you need it.

Moreover, good practice is [define Controller as service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html).

Comment: Few examples of MVC libraries can decidedly fit a particular definition of what MVC is. Symfony2 support MVC if you're so inclined to use and structure it.

Comment: Magento MVC is a really weird example of this.

Comment: Agreed. In answer to the OP, the "best practice" way might look like this: [Moving Away From the Base Controller - Richard Miller](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/06/14/symfony2-moving-away-from-the-base-controller/)

Comment: In short, put common methods in a service class rather than a base class.

Comment: Thank you very much NHG for your post. It is very useful and it helps me a lot the understanding of Symfony2 structure.