# Symfony MVC best practice for controllers

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm

In a Symfony/Doctrine/PHP-project, a client is complaining that we've broken software development best practices. The complaint is about improper layering of the source code, and the lack of unit tests.

- This is a sub $50k-project.
- I believe that the client has an expert from the Java world, perhaps Spring Framework, looking at the source code.

We've been using proper MVC, as we see it.

- View-logic is handled entirely by TWIG.
- Database is handled entirely by Doctrine.
- We're using Symfony Security for access control `($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` and `$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()`.

Beware that Symfony has changed the model a bit, since we started this project - but remains backward compatible.

In the controller the customer is specifically saying that it's wrong for the controller to handle:

- Access Control (via Symfony Security)
- Database Queries (via Doctrine)
- "Parsing and other logic" for sending back responses (`return $this->render('some_template.html.twig');`)

## The question

The client is saying that *best practices is for the controller to simply pass on requests to another layer further down in the system*.

Further he's saying that user-admin is based on a "custom model" where all users and roles are stored in the database - which makes plugging in a different access control system difficult. Specifically because role names seems to be hard coded such as via commands such as `($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')`.

So; is there a definitive best practice on this field? What belongs in the controller, and is Doctrine, Twig, Symfony Security "sufficiently" a separate layer "below the controller".

Should there be yet another layer between the controller and Doctrine for example?

Comment: I'd say that if unit tests were not explicitly an agreed deliverable, the client cannot insist on them (see [this related discussion](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3510/how-do-freelance-coders-persuade-clients-of-the-value-of-software-tests) on _Freelancing_). Do you have functional tests? If you wish to provide one of these, then I'd offer functional tests, since unit tests on their own do not prove that your application works as intended.

Comment: you should have your doctrine queries in entity repositories or some other model format, not in the controller.  Access control would most often be done in the controller, then access-specific functionality run by that controller.  Rendering templates is a controller job, and can also be done in templates to integrate template fragments.

Comment: @halfer Thank you. I'm a Laravel guy, but I'm asking on behalf of a Symphony project which wanted a second opinion. :)

Comment: Symfony, not [Symphony](http://www.getsymphony.com/).

Comment: @DevDonkey The queries are stored in entity repositories.

Comment: "it's wrong for the controller to handle" "Database Queries (via Doctrine)" --- and they are absolutely right.

Comment: "best practices is for the controller to simply pass on requests to another layer further down in the system." --- that's 100% correct. Nothing from what they complain about is specific to Symfony or any other framework, those are generic design concepts.

Comment: @zerkms But isnt passing queries down to Doctrine and using entity repositories doing exactly that? The controller has some logic, as to *where* the queries are sent and *whether or not* the queries are passed on.

Comment: @frodeborli no it does not - your controllers should be unaware of a particular type of storage used. "The controller has some logic" --- and they should not. As per MVC definition those are just a glue layer, between models and presentation layer. And "model layer" is not just your repositories and entities, it's all the business logic.

Comment: A good sign that everything was done "right" is if you can add the new kind of user interface easily, eg: CLI. Can you add CLI to provide all the facilities your project as a web application provides in a cheap fashion?

Comment: @zerkms Doctrine2 is an abstraction that follows the Data Mapper pattern. As such, it abstracts away even the data model. You seem to be advocating the Data Mapper pattern, but there ARE other accepted ways to do things, such as Active Record. In this project however, Data Mapper is used.

Comment: Can you replace the storage with filesystem or remote API? It's not about abstracting from RDBMS, it's about hiding the business logic in a distinct layer (that is called "Model" in terms of MVC, by definition). Anyway, I have put my thoughts which pretty much match to what your customer said (based on extremely limited amount of info you've provided). Now it's you that in charge on making decision on the next move.

Comment: @zerkms Doctrine2 can expose remote data; you would have to write a DBAL "driver". Accessing data is done by means of `$user->getFriends()` and `$user->getAlbums()`. I do consider that to be enough layering. The controller calls `$user->getFriends()` and does not involve itself with the underlying data model. It only cares about the data mapping (the fact that users do have friends).

Comment: I'd say that a user security system that is fully abstracted might also be something that should be part of the spec if was required. Particularly on a low-budget project. But the `isGranted()` call is already pretty high-level and it wouldn't be that difficult to replace the 'security.context' with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://fabien.potencier.org/what-is-symfony2.html

**First, what is Symfony2?**

First, Symfony2 is a reusable set of standalone, decoupled, and cohesive PHP components that solve common web development problems.

Then, based on these components, Symfony2 is also a full-stack web framework.

Depending on your project and depending on your needs, you can either pick and choose some of the Symfony2 components and start your project with them, or you can use the full-stack framework and benefit from the tight integration it provides out of the box. And choosing between the two different approaches is really up to you.

**Is Symfony2 an MVC framework?**

Symfony2 is really about providing the tools for the Controller part, the View part, but not the Model part. It's up to you to create your model by hand or use any other tool, like an ORM. Of course, tight integration exists for the most well known ORMs like Doctrine2 and Propel; but they are optional dependencies. The Symfony2 core features do not and will never rely on any ORM.

Symfony2 is an HTTP framework; it is a Request/Response framework. That's the big deal. The fundamental principles of Symfony2 are centered around the HTTP specification.

**Symfony about best practices:** https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html

You should rly **read this** about controller best practices:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#controllers

You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21701890/2160958

Comment: Please take note of http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing for future reference. Not-citing sources can be seen as plagiarism, and plagiarism is not something we allow on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You edited the source in, after another user pointed out you had copied and pasted your answer from another website. My comment was a friendly reminder that plagiarism isn't tolerated on Stack Overflow; and to please avoid this in future.